# How do i hide side-bar by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am wondering, how can I hide the sidebar menu by default? When I refresh the window, I want the sidebar to be hidden/collapsed.

Answer (score 2):

Without state control, you got [`defaultCollapsed`](https://ant.design/components/layout/#Layout.Sider) property.

> defaultCollapsed  - to set the initial status - type:boolean - default:false

On controlled state just define the initial value of the state:

```
const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(true);
```

If you want to "remember" the last sidebar state after refreshing the page, use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```js
// @utils.js
export const setLSItem = (str, object) => window.localStorage.setItem(str, object);

export const getLSItem = str => window.localStorage.getItem(str);

export const getBooleanLSItem = str => {
  const storageItem = getLSItem(str);
  return storageItem === 'true' || !storageItem ? true : false;
};

// custom hook code
const leftCollapsedInitial =
  getBooleanLSItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS.LEFT_SIDEBAR_IS_VISIBLE)

const useLeftSidebar = () => {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(leftCollapsedInitial);

// On change update the local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    setLSItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS.LEFT_SIDEBAR_IS_VISIBLE, isCollapsed);
  }, [isCollapsed]);

  return [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation you can use defaultCollapsed. You can also use collapsed={true/false} to have a state toogle to open/close the sider.

```
<Sider defaultCollapsed={true} />
```

Comment: That is for the component. I am referring to the Sider Menu Bar for navigation. Thanks!